# 'abrt-cli status' timed out when login to SSH

Tags: ssh, abrt

**Environment**

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.7

abrt-cli version 2.1.11

**Solution**

```
~$ sudo rm -rf .cache
```

re-login

Comment: I think this case can help you dear. https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/the-ssh-login-takes-a-long-time-after-the-login-the-error-message-abrt-cli-status-timed-out-is-displayed/thread/711409-893

Answer (score 7):

```
~$ sudo rm -rf .cache
```

Then re-login.

Comment: This answer is a little light on details. What causes this to happen? How do you prevent it? What is in .cache? What is the effect of deleting it?

Comment: Actually, removing the whole .cache folder is a bad idea. For this specific case, only .cache/abrt would be enough!